# Setters and Getters python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've looked around but everything I tried didn't seem to get any result. I just need to set a custom setter and getter for a class that converts a number to string and viceversa. Since python doesn't support which I'm using a dictionary.

```
class Ship(object):
    def __init__(self, type):
        self.fixed = define_direction()

        self.row = random_row(board, self)
        self.col = random_col(board, self)
        self.type = self.set_type(type)
        print "Type:", str(self.type)

    def set_type(self, type):
        return {
            0 : "Patrol boat",#2
            1 : "Destroyer",#3
            2 : "Submarine",#3
            3 : "Battleship",#4
            4 : "Aircraft carrier",#5
            }.get(type, "Patrol boat") 
    def get_type(self):
        return {
            "Patrol boat" : 0,#2
            "Destroyer" : 1,#3
            "Submarine" : 2,#3
            "Battleship" : 3,#4
            "Aircraft carrier" : 4,#5
              }.get(self.type, 0) 
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Ship. Type: ", self.get_type()
```

Not really sure that `self.type = self.set_type(type)` is legit, but it seems the only way to call a function from inside the class.

In `__init__(self, type)` -> "type" gets passed as a number and it should get converted and stored as a string, than should get reconverted to a number while the getter is called. (maybe there's a better way to do it - using external dictionary to do the conversion and just store the number..?

- PS1: Is it legit to call an external function `random_row(board, self)` and `random_col` passing `self` even if it's not properly initialized or should I move the function inside the class as another setter?
- PS2: calling `__repl__`:

  ```
  def __repr__(self):
    return "Ship. Type: ", str(self.get_type()), str(self.type())
  ```

  returns:

  ```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/xx/Documents/python/battleship/battleship.py", line 85, in <module>
      print ship.__repr__()
    File "/Users/xx/Documents/python/battleship/battleship.py", line 74, in __repr__
      return "Ship. Type: ", str(self.get_type()), str(self.type())
  TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
  ```

  Calling it only on `get_type()`

  ```
  def __repr__(self):
      return "Ship. Type: ", str(self.get_type())
  ```

  returns:

  ```
  Type: Submarine
  ('Ship. Type: ', '2')
  ```

Hope it's clear enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [`@property` decorator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property) to manager your `type` attribute:

```
class Ship(object):
    def __init__(self, type):
        self.fixed = define_direction()

        self.row = random_row(board, self)
        self.col = random_col(board, self)
        self.type = type
        print "Type:", str(self.type)

    @property
    def type(self):
        return {
            "Patrol boat": 0,
            "Destroyer": 1,
            "Submarine": 2,
            "Battleship": 3,
            "Aircraft carrier": 4,
        }.get(self._type, 0) 

    @type.setter
    def type(self, type):
        self._type = {
            0: "Patrol boat",
            1: "Destroyer",
            2: "Submarine",
            3: "Battleship",
            4: "Aircraft carrier",
        }.get(type, "Patrol boat") 

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Ship. Type: " + self._type
```

Your `__repr__` should always return a string; you were returning a tuple instead. Your error was caused by your `self.type()` call; since `self.type` stores a string in your code, you were trying to treat that string as a callable.

It is fine to call other functions (outside of the class) from `__init__`; it is just another method on your instance really, just take into account what attributes have and haven't been set yet. However, if the function relies on information on `self` and has no uses outside the class, I'd move it into the class with a `_` prefix to indicate that it is internal to the class implementation.